# How to avoid Mono#block() when using reactive in rest API logic

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

So the problem is as follows:

1. I am exposing API to register user within my service
2. Before I am going to register user, I want to validate him in external service (rest API)
3. I want to inform user with proper response status whether he was created (201 or some error code)

My code to create user looks like that:

```java
  @Transactional
  public void createUser(UserDto userDto) {
    UserEntity newUser = userFactory.createUser(userDto);
    String userId = userDto.getUserId();

    externalApiService
        .validateUser(userId)
        .subscribe(a-> userRepository.save(newUser));
  }
```

and validation of user is as follows:

```java
  public Mono<Void> validateUser(String userId) {
    return webClient
        .get(...)
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(Void.class);
    //Exact request is bit more complicated, but those details shouldn't be crucial in this example
  }
```

My endpoint that is utilizing this looks like that:

```java
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto dto) {
    userService.createUser(dto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

This is quite easy when I use blocking `RestTemplate` or use `block()` on `Mono` that I just got from `WebClient`. If there is an exception from REST call to external service my global exception handler will do the job and respond user with proper response code.

But what if I want to utilize full power of reactive programming and don't want to `block()`. I cannot figure out how to properly do this. Can anyone give me some advice?

And please excuse me if my question is trivial, I am quite new to `WebClient` and reactive programming at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebClient` is a reactive client and the only way to use it with non-reactive Spring MVC is to `block`.

To make the flow fully non-blocking, all components/functions should be reactive. You would need to switch to Spring WebFlux and also make `createUser` reactive.

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> createUser(@RequestBody UserDto dto) {
    return userService.createUser(dto)
            .map(user -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build());
}
```

This code assumes that `createUser` is reactive

```
public static Mono<UserEntity> createUser(UserDto dto) {
    ...
}
```

In case `userRepository` is not reactive you could wrap non-reactive code and run it on a separate scheduler [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking).